# Is VCT(volts center tapped) voltage between two outer taps or betwen outer tap and center tap?

Tags: transformer, datasheet

I am not quite sure is VCT(volts center tapped) voltage between one of outer taps and center tap or between two outer taps?

In wikipedia it is said: Volts center tapped (VCT) describes the voltage output of a center tapped transformer. 
Kinda gives me nothing..

From this thread [How to differentiate center-tapped power transformer from a non center-tapped one?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/153405/how-to-differentiate-center-tapped-power-transformer-from-a-non-center-tapped-on) one could conclude that it means voltage between outer taps.

For example: will 241-8-24 from https://belfuse.com/resources/241.pdf give me 24V between center tap and outer tap or between both outer taps?

please advise,
thanks in advance

Comment: Please add a schematic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> For example: will 241-8-24 give me 24V between center tap and outer
>   tap or between both outer taps?

Answer: between both outer taps is 24 volts.

The device you listed has a secondary voltage of 24 volts and a centre tap so, if you were to use the centre-tap and one of the outer connections to the secondary you would get 12 V RMS out. Another way of describing this output that is sometimes used is "12-0-12". This implies that you get 12V AC either side of the centre tap that is referenced (for convenience) as 0 volts.